# find required subobject in list of list of list of.. objects

Tags: python, list, suds

I'm working with suds, and to implement receiving and sending attachments (I already done it), I need to work somewhere with "low" level suds objects. One of those objects, that is used to generate SOAP XML, have this structure (pseudo code):

```
struct object
[
    [string] name
    [list of objects] children
]
```

When I receive this object, I have to check:

- that it has name "document",
- then choose his child with name "Envelope",
- then choose his child with name "Body",
- then choose his child with name "UpdateRequest",
- then choose his child with name "model",
- then choose his child with name "instance",
- then choose his child with name "attachments"

And then work with that subtree. How to take this subtree (and check if it exists) pythonic style?
While I tested it, I used this way:

```
attachments_tree = soap_xml.children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].children[1].children[21]
```

But I want something like:

```
attachments_tree = soap_xml["document"]["Envelope"]["Body"]["UpdateRequest"]["model"]["instance"]["attachments"]
```

I'm sure converting to dictionary is bad idea. 
Trying invoking subtree step by step like here:

```
Envelopes = [child for child in soap_xml.children if child.name == 'Envelope']
Body = [child for child in Envelopes[0].children if child.name == 'Body']
```

Is also looks bad, even if that will works. Is there good pythonic solution?

Comment: Ugly business logic never begets pretty code. You do what you have to do to work with what you've been handed.

Comment: You probably should be using XPATH for things like this

Comment: Did you take a look at named tuples?

Comment: No, but I really don't understand how that should help, because object that I described is what I receive from suds, and what I have to parse... I guess it has no named tuples.